# Allegro 5: al_create_display() fails

Tags: c, allegro5

I'm attempting to create a simple display with allegro lib, but unfortunately al_create_display() fails and returns NULL. The point is I don't know what is wrong. I've read that it could be caused by a graphics driver.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I think allegro has been installed properly.

Code:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display=NULL;
    if(!al_init()){
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't initialize allegro!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(!al_init_primitives_addon()){
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't initialize primitives addon!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    display=al_create_display(600,600);
    if(!display) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't create allegro display!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_draw_line(100,100,400,400,al_map_rgb(255,0,0),3);
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(1.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help & regards.